# Readmine doesn`t send mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, redmine

I add to configuration.yml email settings. But notifications not come to email. I try to send test mail from settings page, but also I doesn`t recieve any emails.

configuration.yml:

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    smtp_settings:
      address: mail.mysite.ru
      port: 587
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "redmine@mysite.ru"
      password: "mypass"
```

Production.log (https://yadi.sk/d/31jli2yOiraHn[1](https://yadi.sk/d/31jli2yOiraHn)) doesn`t contains mail errors, redmine.error.log is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're missing smtp settings for development/production environment. If so, try

```
default: &default
  email_delivery:
    smtp_settings:
      # Your settings

development:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
  # Override default settings if necessary
  user_name: "redmine@othersite.ru"
  password: "otherpass"
```

Since you're using port 587, I suppose your smtp server uses StartTLS to secure mail exchanges. So you have to add the following line in your `smtp_settings`:

```
enable_starttls_auto: true
```

And if the smtp server is using untrusted SSL certification, then add this line too:

```
openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
```

Try sending email again. If still not working, then try changing `authentication: :login` to `authentication: :plain`.